# How can I open an app with Siri Shortcuts?

Tags: ios12, sirishortcuts

[image]
I am getting this error when I attempt to opecannotp in Siri Shortcut:

> “Shortcuts can not open the app for the URL scheme “prefs” .  The app may not be installed on the device”

The app is installed. I’ve tried opening it and reinstalling. This is the only app I my device that causes this error. Any ideas?